# I facing a problem in set up selenium in virtual studio code for python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_location = "/Users/Sony/Desktop/XUAN/Python/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://sapsnkra.moe.gov.my/ibubapa2/')
input(" ")
```

```
PS C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\XUAN\Python> python -u "c:\Users\Sony\Desktop\XUAN\Python\Python Project\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sony\Desktop\XUAN\Python\Python Project\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to automatically manage your chromedriver version.

You can use it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://sapsnkra.moe.gov.my/ibubapa2/')
input(" ")
```